# How to find 5th city which sell more products in MSSQL / SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have queried so far and it is all right. The only thing I want is to find 5th city but instead it queries all 5 cities. I will appreciate if anybody can give me a hand. Thanks ahead.

```
SELECT TOP 5 SUM    (fact.sale.Quantity) as quantity,   Dimension.City.City     FROM    fact.Sale 
INNER JOIN    Dimension.City
on   fact.Sale.[City Key] = Dimension.city.[City Key]
GROUP BY Dimension.city.City
ORDER BY SUM(quantity)    desc
```

Comment: Another alternative - take the top 1 (ascending) of the top 5 (descending). Consider carefully what should happen when you have ties within the top 5 values. Or you have less than 5 values.

Answer (score 2):

Top 5 will return all top 5 city.

Instead use row_number() function to add index and select 5th index.

Comment: you mean instead of top to use row_number?

Answer (score 0):

@javid-hesenov I think SQL code below is what @Arjun meant. @Arjun please verified. Thanks.

```
WITH CTE AS (
SELECT SUM(fact.sale.Quantity) as quantity, 
       Dimension.City.City as city,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY SUM(fact.sale.Quantity) DESC) as index  
FROM fact.Sale 
INNER JOIN Dimension.City
on fact.Sale.[City Key] = Dimension.city.[City Key]
GROUP BY Dimension.city.City
)
SELECT quantity, city
FROM CTE
WHERE index = 5;
```

### UPDATE: Solution without Common Table Expression.

```
SELECT quantity, city 
FROM (
    SELECT SUM(fact.sale.Quantity) as quantity, 
           Dimension.City.City as city,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY SUM(fact.sale.Quantity) DESC) as index  
    FROM fact.Sale 
    INNER JOIN Dimension.City
    on fact.Sale.[City Key] = Dimension.city.[City Key]
    GROUP BY Dimension.city.City
) as tbl_sq
WHERE index = 5;
```

Comment: Thanks JK Chai, it worked ))). But i wonder if there is another way to do it without WITH.?
Thanks ahead

Comment: @JavidHesenov Yes, you can do a subquery, but I believe Common Table Expression is more efficient and better approach for querying larger datasets.